# How to find a subset of columns of a matrix which spans the entire range of matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to know the best method (in terms of time complexity) by which i can choose a subset of K columns from L columns of a matrix that can span the entire range of matrix.

Gauss elimination, QR and SVD based decomposition are good options but the complexity is approx of the order O(n^3) for a square matrix of size (nxn). I want to know if some method exist which have complexity say O(n) or O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Transpose the matrix and apply Gauß's row reduction: the transposes of the non-zero rows are the linear combinations ofthe columns that span the  range of the matrix. The corresponding columns of the original matrix are the subset of v=columns you're looking for.

In addition, doing the same operations on the unit matrix gives you the linear relations between the other columns and this subset.

Comment: Thanks for ans. But my aim is a method with linear time complexity. QR and SVD based decomposition is better than Gauss elimination but the complexity is approx of the order O(n^3) for a square matrix of size (nxn). I want a method have complexity say O(n) or O(n^2).